# copying a row from one sheet to another automatically based on information in one column and sorted by dated (into Months)

Tags: vba, excel

Right, I'm having an issue that I'm hoping one (or more) of you will be able to help me with.

For a week now, I've been trying to work out how I can automatically copy and update rows from one sheet in my Workbook to separate sheets based on the month of a date in the second column.

I've tried everything I can think of, VLOOKUP doesn't seem to do it and I know little about VBA to be able to work out how it may work.

I did find a solution that looked promising Using VBA, that split all the varying rows based on the different values in one of the columns (I created an extra column and formatted it to text and then put JAN 15, FEB 15 etc.) then created new tabs and inserted the data into those. Unfortunately, for some reason this ended up creating excess tabs and wouldn't update the breakdown sheets when I changed the Master sheet.

The code I found was:

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 1        
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")        
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:C1"            
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Now, what I'd really like is for excel to search through the dates in column C, and depending on month, move them into the relevant sheet, but in a way that if I update the main sheet, the monthly sheets are updated automatically. I don't know if this is possible, but surely it must be (it probably isn't even difficult). If necessary, I'd be happy to put in a further column with "Jan 15", "Feb 15" etc. or have a button that I can press to update everything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like a bit of an overkill, here I wrote a piece of code that would do the job if extended a bit, you need to add some cases, secure from errors in case the sheet is already there, and adjust the paste location but its a start(will also have more learning value for ya) :)

```
Sub haha()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow

Select Case Format(ws.Range("c" & i).Value, "mm")

Case "01"

Sheets.Add.Name = "Jan"
ws.Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Jan").Range("A1")


End Select
Next i
End Sub
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

If it were going to be a code that you wanted to put to a button, I would do something like:

```
dim b2 as Workbook
Set b2=ThisWorkbook

xrowx=1
datecol='whatever column that you have the "Feb15" "Jan 15" data in

Do While xrowx<=Worksheetfunction.CountA(b2.Sheets(1).Range("A:A"))


month=Left(b2.Sheet(1).cells(xrowx,datecol))

if month="Jan" then
    emptyrow=Worksheetfunction.CountA(b2.sheets(2).Range("A:A")+1

    col=1

    Do While col<=datecol
    b2.sheets(2).cells(emptyrow,col)=b2.Sheets(1).Cells(emptyrow,col)
    col=col+1

    Loop

elseif month="Feb" then
    emptyrow=Worksheetfunction.CountA(b2.sheets(3).Range("A:A")+1

    col=1

    Do While col<=datecol
    b2.sheets(3).cells(emptyrow,col)=b2.Sheets(1).Cells(emptyrow,col)
    col=col+1

    Loop

elseif ...

...'continue on in this manner for all months

xrowx=xrowx+1

Loop
```

It's not super pretty or the most optimized way to get it done, but it is easy to understand and should give you a decent framework to build something that suites your needs well (Note: this code could also be used to auto-update as part of a built in sheet macro, but due to the fact that with very large data sets it will be a bit sluggish, that' not recommended)

Comment: Hey, I've given that a shot and edited it where I think is appropriate, I seem to be coming across an error it comes up with "Compile error: invalid outside procedure" ... is there something obvious I'm missing out?

Comment: @Geelanco could you like the like of code that is throwing that error for?

Comment: It appears to be "Set b2 = ThisWorkbook" ... do I need to edit parts like that to reflect the actual name? ... similarly, I know I'm being an idiot, but with the 'If Month = "Jan" Then' line, do I need to substitute any of that depending on my spreadsheet?

Comment: also, if not, does that mean I could use my pre-existing date column to pull the date from?

Comment: You should not have to change change that line (`Set b2 = ThisWorkbook`) to any other name unless you changed the `Dim b2 as Workbook` line. (I always use b2 as my workbook name when I code in VBA. Just a habit of mine, you could use any name in stead of b2). Also, you shouldn't have to change the `'If Month = "Jan" Then` line, that should work fine, but the `month=Left(b2.Sheet(1).cells(xrowx,datecol))` line may need to be edited depending on how you change b2 and which sheet is your main sheet (using `Sheets(1)` as opposed to `Sheets("Sheet1")` uses the actual sheet reference instead of the

Comment: sheet name, which means that you may need to change that reference(or not)). And, yes, you could use your pre-exsisting date column, but you would need to use something esle to compare it to other than `"Jan"` or `"Feb"` as those are only strings, not dates.

Comment: right, that makes a lot of sense to me! ... if I wanted to change the comparison data, could I use an asterisk like I might in a function? so instead of "Jan" I'd have "*01/2015"?

Comment: I don't think so, unless that is the format that the data is in your date column. Putting quotes around things turns that piece of data into a string, which VBA considers words. When comparing two words, if they aren't exactly the same, they come up with a `False` (no match result). You could use the [`DATEDIFF()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php) built in function to compare the months though.